# Determine MP4 video from regular Embed code

Tags: facebook, embed, html5-video, mp4

I'm 99% sure the answer is *No*, but worth a shot as you never know...

The typical "copy & paste" embed code for uploaded Facebook videos goes like this:

```
<object width="400" height="300" ><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
  <param name="movie" value="http://www.facebook.com/v/12345678910111213" />
  <embed src="http://www.facebook.com/v/12345678910111213" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" width="400" height="300"></embed>
</object>
```

From this, is there any way to determine what the MP4 url is?

Alternatively, YouTube and Vimeo have provided access to a "*HTML5*" friendly embed using an `IFRAME`. Is there a Facebook equivalent?

And yes, using the [Graph API you can get `embed_html`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/) but I deliberately want to avoid that route.

Thanks.

Comment: be interested if your 1% was a yes. Good quesiton mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the link direct to the video from `src` attribute of the FQL video table.

If you're looking for any video belonging to the user:

`fql?q=SELECT src FROM video WHERE owner=me()`

or if you have the video ID:

`fql?q=SELECT src FROM video WHERE vid=2031763147233`

and if you need the HQ version query for `src_hq` instead of `src`

Comment: I was hoping to avoid FQL but it seems that it the only way